# Is there any way to see the current results for the Unix/Linux and Ubuntu merger poll?

Tags: feature-request, polling

https://askubuntu.com/polls/1/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-merge

Is there a way to see the current results? Even after voting the results are not shown. Since it's a "community vote" I think the results should be somehow shown for the users.

This would also be useful to avoid accusations such as "the poll results were doctored; you just wanted to give us the illusion of a community decision".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only mods can see the tally, when the voting is over we will release the results

Comment: Any reason for this? I think it would be nice if everyone could see it, in the name of "being open"